# Guide to save money in all-time life

Tags: savings, rent, france

First, let's assume I've no skill in trading and finance, I'm just a young French student that want to save money.

A friend told me things like that, many times :

> - 10% of budget should be for drink or eat outside, no more.
> - Your rent is about 500€/750€ (my salary), it's too much, even if you get 250€ to help (from my state)

Is there a "guide" that tell you how much you have to/should use to save money all month, depending of my ambition ?

(Except all tips to save money at shop, when I've buying food etc, I already know them.)

Then I want to invest my money, but that's another question that I will be able to ask in two days..

Comment: Be careful about applying 'general guides' as strict rules to your own life. They may be either too strict or too lenient, but either way rules of thumb are just that - general principles.

Answer (score 2):

You will find lots of rules of thumb but there is no universal truth to how much you should save. There are factors you DO need to consider though:

- you should start as early as possible to set money aside for retirement. You should then use a retirement calculator to at least get an understanding of the amount you need to set aside each month to achieve the desired retirement income;
- your default should be not to spend money and only spend money when you must. Leisure, travel and eating out should come last *after you have saved up*;
- you should have funds for different terms. For example, my wife and I have an emergency fund for unexpected expenses or losses in income. The rule of thumb here generally is to have 3-6 months of salary saved up. A longer term fund should be created for larger expenses like buying a car or preparing the cashdown on a property. Finally, the retirement fund which should cover your needs after you have retired.

Comment: Living in France, income from retirement are given by state, depending of how much your salary was in your life and how many time you worked.
First point still apply to that ?

3-6 months salary saved up will be my first objective ! Thanks !

Comment: I may be missing context on France's retirement plans, but I would be wary of completely depending on government to fund your retirement. What if rules change and this social benefit is no longer available or is available but significantly reduced or altered ?

Comment: Nice thinking. What's a safe income from retirement ?
The safest I can think is to rent an appartment. Or many.. but it seem like it cost a lot.

Comment: Again, there is no single answer to that and it depends on many factors such as your appetite for risk, savings, etc. Investing in rental properties can be a good source of income but also comes with very high upfront fees / investments and responsibilities (building maintenance and repairs, tenant management, etc). Also, most would agree that they are definitely *not* the safest investment. This topic being too broad to be answered in a comment, I suggest reading on the different investment categories that interest you and ask targeted questions if you have any.